# Help understand a proof in the paper "Likelihood Ratio Tests for Monotone Functions"

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, summation-by-parts

I'm reading the paper [Likelihood Ratio Tests for Monotone Functions](http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/%7Emoulib/lrtfundamental.pdf) by Moulinath Banerjee and Jon A. Wellner. I got stuck at equality 2.8, where the authors used summation by parts to derive 2.8 from 2.7.

Suppose we have $\Delta_i \sim Bernoulli(\omega_i)$, we want to obtain the $\hat{\omega_i}$ that maximize the log-likelihood

$$\Phi(\omega_1, \omega_2, ..., \omega_m) = \sum_{i=1}^m \bigg\{\Delta_i\log\omega_i + (1 - \Delta_i)\log (1-\omega_i)\bigg\}\ ,$$

under the constaint that
$$0 < \omega_1 \leq \omega_2 \leq ... \leq \omega_m \leq \theta_0\ .$$

For such $\hat{\omega_i}$ to exist, the authors claimed that

$$\sum_{i=1}^m \left[\frac{\Delta_i}{\hat{\omega_i}} - \frac{1 - \Delta_i}{1 - \hat{\omega_i}}\right]\hat{\omega_i} = \sum_{i=1}^m \left[\frac{\Delta_i}{\hat{\omega_i}} - \frac{1 - \Delta_i}{1 - \hat{\omega_i}}\right] \theta_0$$ has to hold.

To prove the claim, the authors started from the concavity of $\Phi$, by defining $$S_i = \sum_{j\leq i} \left[ \frac{\Delta_j}{\hat{\omega_j}} - \frac{1 - \Delta_j}{1 - \hat{\omega_j}} \right]\ , i=1, ..., m\ ,$$

then

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\Phi((1-t)\hat{\omega} + t\omega)\bigg\rvert_{t=0} &=  \sum_{i=1}^m \left[\frac{\Delta_i}{\hat{\omega_i}} - \frac{1 - \Delta_i}{1 - \hat{\omega_i}}\right](\omega_i - \hat{\omega_i}) \tag{2.7}\\
&= -\sum_{i=1}^m S_i\left[\omega_{i+1} - \omega_i  - (\hat{\omega_{i+1}} - 
 \hat{\omega_i})\right] \tag{2.8}\\
&\leq 0\ .
\end{align}

What makes me confused was how to derive equation (2.8) from (2.7). The authors said they used summation by parts, with $\hat{\omega}_{i+1} = \omega_{i+1} = \theta_0$. Could anyone help me to understand how this summation by parts works here?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you for the suggestion. I've added some contexts up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\sigma_N:=\sum_{n=0}^Na_nb_n$ and $B_n:=\sum_{k=0}^nb_k$. General summation by parts looks like:

$$\sigma_N=a_NB_N-\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}B_n(a_{n+1}-a_n).$$

So let $b_i:=\frac{\Delta_i}{\hat{\omega}_i}-\frac{1-\Delta_i}{1-\hat{\omega}_i}$ and $a_i:=\omega_i-\hat{\omega}_i$.

Are you able to see the result from here?